# Instance of Future<Dynamic> when function returns

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

```
        Future<void> fetchplace() async {
          final dataList = await DBHelper.fetchdata('subjects');
          List item

         _items = dataList
         .map(
          (item)=> Subjects(item['id'],item['subject'],
                item['percentage'],
                item['total'],
                attend(item['id']),
                item['leave'],
                item['current'],
                item['present'],),
        ).toList();

    notifyListeners();

     }



    Future<void> attend(String id) async {

      final data= await DBHelper.fetchdataattend('data$id',id);
      final loc= data.map((e){

           return e['attend'];

      }).toList();

      print(loc);
      return loc;

      }
```

It first goes to the fetchplace Function from where it does to the attend function but when it returns the attend variable returns 'Instance To Future'.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

In dart when u have async function the return type is Future<...> this (...) are the return type of function. In your case u declarate void return (Future< void>), but you are returning "loc" variable.
You can switch it to

```
Future attend(String id) async {
```

or

```
Future<dynamic> attend(String id) async {
```

Comment: No it did not work. My question is when I call fetchdata Ot collects all information from the Database before attend(item[id]) is executed. Attend function finishes execution Inreturn from fetchdata function. How to I make sure attend is executed before fetchdata.